# Class array in Flash as2?

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-2

I was wondering if it was possible to create an array of classes in Flash. Is it possible to do like in C++ where you can do the following?

```
CDog dog[100];
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    dog[i] = new Dog();
}
```

If the above is applicable to flash, the syntax must be different because I was not able to get it working.

I tried using Array, but I think it only works for strings, and integers. I was not able to get it working with classes.

Thanks

Comment: If a class is considered an object, then yes. I want to create an array of my Enemy class so that I can access them via enemy[i].

Comment: an object is an instantiated class usually assigned to a var of some sort so you can save the "object" or the var in an element of an array

Comment: Flash AS3 uses ECMAScript, so the syntax for declaring an array is different than what you're trying to use.

Comment: Is it even possible to make an array of classes similar to the example I showed above?

Answer (score 2):

Its been a long long time since AS2 and you might want to consider moving up to AS3 since it is much more OOP orientated.
I haven't touched AS2 in years but the code would look something like.

```
var aDogs:Array = [];
for ( var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    aDogs[i] = new Dog();
}
```